# How to get broadcast state Steam API

Tags: java, streaming, broadcast, steam, steam-web-api

I have a list of "followed" steam users and I'm trying to find an endpoint to poll which ones are currently broadcasting. I was initially trying to determine this based on some properties of a Steam User namely:

- persona state
- profile state
- community visibility state
- game info

It seems however this is only marginally useful for your friends as friends can only be streaming if they are online and in a game (from what I can tell).

For non-friends it seems their's no connection at all. Game info can be hidden but they can still be streaming publicly. Offline users and one's with private profiles can also have a public broadcast running. There has to be some kind of endpoint to check a user's current broadcast state right?

One solution I explored was doing a quick load of the MPD but using that endpoint also triggers the starting of a user's stream that is currently inactive due to no viewers and I don't want to do that.

The main problem seems to be lack of documentation. The best I've found is some third party site here: https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html and it only lists a few of the broadcasting related endpoints

Comment: Not sure there is any way except https://steamcommunity.com/broadcast/getbroadcastmpd/?steamid=76561198838606142. There is also ISteamVideo::IsBroadcasting interface in C++ sdk, but you will need to have a steam running on the same machine

Comment: @stanjer that's the conclusion I've come to as well. It kind of sucks because this request will also start the user's broadcast if it's not currently running (and inform them that someone's watching) so it's not suitable for a simple broadcast state check